# C++ cout wrong number in array

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ and I find a weird result when I run code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* arrayTest(){
  int arr[3] = {1, 2, 3};
  int * poi = arr;
  return poi;
}

int main(){
  int* arr = arrayTest();
  for (int i = 0; i <3; i++){
    cout << *(arr+i) << endl;
 }
 return 0;
}
```

result is:

```
./a.out
1
0
167772160
```

What's wrong with this code?

`g++ --version
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.2.0`

Thank you.

Comment: You are returning a pointer to an object that is local, which thus ceases to exist after the function exits, a.k.a. a dangling pointer. Make sure you turn on warnings, the compiler might have told you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an issue with the design of this function:

```
int* arrayTest() {
  int arr[3] = {1, 2, 3};
  int * poi = arr;
  return poi;
}
```

The variable `arr` is a local variable (in official C-speak, it has "automatic storage duration"). This means that as soon as the function returns, the memory associated with that array is reclaimed and recycled for future use.

The problem here is that you've made a pointer (`poi`) to the array. When you return that pointer, it points back to where `arr` used to be in memory, except that, alas, upon returning from the function `arr` has shuffled off this mortal coil and no longer exists. You now have a *dangling pointer*, which means that it's pointing at whatever unfortunate object happens to get placed in memory where `arr` used to be. This leads to undefined behavior, meaning that anything can happen (in your case, the program prints garbage values.)